# Call to undefined function: date_create_from_format() in php 5.3.X

Tags: php, date, architecture

I'm using [date_create_from_format](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) and it returns me the error

```
Fatal error;:  Call to undefined function  date_create_from_format()
```

only in a particular environment...

```
php 5.3.X / SMP Thu Jul 21 17:28:56 EDT 2011 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux
```

it's working fine on...

```
 php 5.3.X / Ubuntu SMP Tue Sep 13 19:39:17 UTC 2011 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I'm wondering if there's not any switch in the config or something that I am missing? I'm kinda clueless right now.

Comment: What is the .X? Run php -v to get the full version number, but be sure the command line version is the same as the web version.

Comment: on the ok server it's `5.3.2-1ubuntu4.10` and on the troubled one it's `5.3.8`. requirement on [php.net](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php): (PHP 5 >= 5.3.0)

Comment: Sorry, I don't know. It is possible to disable functions in php, but I can't imaging why someone would. My only suggestion is to try other functions in that library and see what you find. For exmaple: `$now   = new DateTime;`

Comment: oh! looks like I have a DateTime problem. if I print_r the object on the faulty server: `DateTime Object ( )` if I do the same on the working server `DateTime Object ( [date] => 2011-11-01 22:38:47 [timezone_type] => 3 [timezone] => America/New_York )`

Comment: Try the code here: http://us.php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php#refsect1-datetime.construct-examples (the exception or `date_get_last_errors()`) and see what it prints.

Comment: Thanks Ariel this really help. the exception is the following: `DateTime::__construct() [datetime.--construct]: It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected 'America/New_York' for 'EDT/-4.0/DST' instead`.

Comment: Therefore, the timezone seems correctly setup on the faulty server. The only difference I see is the `"Olson" Timezone Database Version` which is set to `2010.9` on the faulty server and to `0.system` on the ok one.

Comment: Did you use `date_default_timezone_set()` like it says? Try that first.

Comment: Thanks for the help. see my final thoughts in the answer comments. regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.php.net is your friend. According to their docs DateTime fxs are part of the core (http://us.php.net/manual/en/datetime.installation.php), so no need for custom compilation flag. Configs can be set (http://us.php.net/manual/en/datetime.configuration.php) but none of these look like they would ave anything to do with your issue.

You may want to do a `date` on the troubled server via the command line and see if it's set correctly.

Comment: date looks ok on both environment `Nov 1 02:07:01 EDT 2011`

Comment: On the system with the known issue, try a simple call to Date::createFromFormat() and see if it works. http://us.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php

Comment: please see my latest comment in the original question comments. thanks.

Comment: Weird, whats the timezone set to on the fault server's php.ini file?

Comment: please see my latest comments in the original question comments. regards.

Comment: That warning that PHP is throwing is b/c the PHP devs increased the error level. This is a known fix that we need to make when upgrading from php 5.x.x to 5.3.x. In your php.ini file find the date.timezone line and see if it's set... Mine looks like `date.timezone = UTC`

Comment: thanks for the help. So, for the record, this can be solved by defining date.timezone in the php.ini or by specifying a tz with date_default_timezone_set() in the code. IMO the code solution is cleaner thus more flexible.

Comment: Glad it works, my only issue with the code solution is that it won't be universal, I'd highly recommend you set it via php.ini so you won't end up in any timezone snafus down the road.